# Quarkus - Azure Function - Application Setting

Tags: quarkus

I've a Quarkus application running as an Azure Function. The application references a value from the Application settings defined in the Function App. This works fine. When I change the value in the Application setting than it's not picked up by Quarkus. Does Quarkus monitor any changes in Application settings or do we need to restart the Function App?

Answer (score 0):

Quarkus does **not** monitor configuration changes - this has been discussed a few times on the [dev mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/quarkus-dev) but there has never been a concensus on the proper approach (while preserving the Quarkus DNA)

Comment: OK... than I have to look for a different solution. The application setting references a KeyVault secret. I've restarted the Azure Function after a change in the secret but the it's not always picked up...